# How to track changes to a GORM-managed collection?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Imagine the following domain classes:

```
class User {
    static hasMany = [ roles: Role ]
    List<Role> roles
    User() {
        roles = new ObservableList<>()
        roles.addPropertyChangeListener({ event -> ... } as PropertyChangeListener)
    }
}

class Role {
    String name
}
```

My intention is to perform some actions each time an element is added to / removed from the `roles` collection; this includes 1) populating `roles` from database, and 2) further manipulation by a user. If a User instance is just created (and not persisted), I am able to catch notifications. After the call to save() method, the ObservableList is still intact. But later, for example, when I perform a User.find...() from a controller, the original `ObservableList` is replaced by Hibernate's `org.hibernate.collection.PersistentList`, and obviously there are no notifications anymore.

How can I implement a change-aware list that would be compatible with GORM?

Comment: What changes are you trying to track?

Comment: Adding and removing element(s). The element itself should be accessible from a notification handler.

Comment: Have you looked at hooking into GORM events? http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping